# Definition of 'enumerator' in C#

Tags: c#

What is the meaning of enumerator in C#?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An enumerator helps you enumerate (iterate) over a collection of items.

You can infer the purpose by simply looking at the [members of the IEnumerator Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx). More specifically, the Enumerator knows exactly where you are in the collection (the current item) and where the next item is (the MoveNext method).

Check out the Wikipedia article on the Iterator:

[Iterator - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator)

Answer (score 11):

"Enumerator" is the .NET Framework's name for *iterators*. The Wikipedia page on iterators contains a nice introduction to that topic:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#C.23_and_other_.NET_languages

For information specific to the .NET implementation, the MSDN page of the `IEnumerator` interface contains more details:

- [IEnumerator(T) Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx)

In general, an iterator allows you to loop through a collection. In C#, iterators are used most commonly *implicity* through the [`foreach` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx):

```
foreach (myType o in myCollection)
{
    // do something with o
}
```

This is equivalent to the following explicit usage of the iterator:

```
IEnumerator<myType> iter = myCollection.GetEnumerator();
while (iter.MoveNext())
{
    var o = iter.Current;
    // do something with o
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IEnumerable and IEnumarable have a method called GetEnumerator() which returns an Enumerator object

The enumerator exposes the GetNext() Method which is pretty self explanatory.

Enumerators are what enable the foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

You use an enumerator to iterate over a collection of items.

One nice way to do this type of thing is C# is using the `foreach` loop.

Ex:

```
IList<string> actors = new List<string>();
actors.Add("Chuck Norris");
actors.Add("Denzel Washington");
actors.Add("Sylvester Stallone");

// iterate over the list using foreach
foreach (string actor in actors)
{
    //...
}
```