# What does a HashSet Enumerator do?

Tags: c#, collections, iterator, hashset, enumerator

I'm not used to write C# code, only Java and Python.
Now I found some code example for an algorithm which is only available in C#.
There is one structure I don't understand, it is the Enumerator.

```
HashSet<Node>.Enumerator enumerator = hashSet.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
Item next = enumerator.Current;
```

So `Item` is the data type stored in the HashSet `hashSet`. Is this equal to a for-loop iterating over a HashSet or how else can that be translated into python or java?

Comment: For a simple collection where its elements can be accessed by index, then yes, it's equivalent to a for loop. In reality, a custom enumerator could perform any number of actions when you call `MoveNext()` before completing and providing a different value for `Current`.

Comment: Do you know the concept of an iterator (a famous design pattern). It's that.

Comment: [Possible duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415107/definition-of-enumerator-in-c-sharp) (if not, please let us know what this one doesn't answer for you).

Comment: The `foreach` loop is more or less syntactic sugar that hides the usage of an enumerator. So yes, iterating using `enumerator.MoveNext()` or `foreach` are essentially the same. But you cannot iterate for instance a `HashSet` using a `(for int i = 0; i < ...)` loop, because you can't access elements in a `HashSet` by an index ...

Comment: [Getting an enumerator that iterates through HashSet<T>](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-getting-an-enumerator-that-iterates-through-hashsett/) | [IEnumerable in C#](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-ienumerable) | [IEnumerable.GetEnumerator Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator) | [A Beginner's Tutorial on Implementing IEnumerable Interface and Understanding yield Keyword](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474678/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Implementing-IEnumerable-I)

Comment: **If an answer is helpful, you should accept it by clicking tick at left.**

Answer (score 2):

`GetEnumerator()` methods are presented in some data structures in C# such as `List`, `Set`, etc. It enables doing iteration through. Actually, `foreach` internally makes use of it.

---

`foreach` statement is to iterate through the elements of certain data structures. A `foreach` can be used when all of the following conditions hold:

- The data structure implements either `IEnumerable`(which is to
  satisfy legacy codes before generics) or `IEnumerable<T>` for some
  type `T`.
- You do not need to know the locations in the data structure of the
  individual elements.

For example, the `string` class implements both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<Char>`.

The `IEnumerable<T>` interface implies the data structure requires two methods:

- `public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()`
- `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`

The latter method is required only because `IEnumerable<T>` is a subtype of `IEnumerable`, and that interface requires a `GetEnumerator` method that returns a *non-generic* `IEnumerator`. Both of these methods should return the same object; hence, because `IEnumerator<T>` is also a subtype of `IEnumerator`, this method can simply call the first method:

```
System.Collections.IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

As you can see, the `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` method returns a reference to another interface named `System.Collections.IEnumerator`. This interface provides the infrastructure to allow the caller to traverse the internal objects contained by the IEnumerable-compatible container:

```
public interface IEnumerator
{
   bool MoveNext (); // Advance the internal position of the cursor.
   object Current { get;} // Get the current item (read-only property).
   void Reset (); // Reset the cursor before the first member.
}
```

Let's exemplify it.

```
public class PowersOfThree : IEnumerable<int>
{      
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new PowersOfThreeEnumerator();
    }       
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }       
}


internal class PowersOfThreeEnumerator : IEnumerator<int>
{
    private int index = 0;

    public int Current
    {
        get { return (int)System.Math.Pow(3, index); }
    }

    object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        index++;

        if (index > 10)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        index = 0;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

public class Test 
{
    public static void Main(string[] str)
    {
        var p2 = new PowersOfThree();
        foreach (int p in p2)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
    }
}
```

`Current` method returns the same element until `MoveNext` method is called. The initial index is `0` each `MoveNext` method increments the index from `1` to 10, inclusively, then it returns `false`. When the enumerator is at this position, subsequent calls to `MoveNext` also return `false`.

Do you see that what happened to `Current` when `MoveNext` returned `false`? Can you set `Current` to the first element of the collection again?
If you don't reinstantiate new enumerator, no.